# How to run two agents in parallel in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In this release pipeline, I have two tasks: one is running the `kubectl` command, and I need it to keep running while I run the second task. After researching for a while, I know that parallel tasks are not available in Azure DevOps, so I tried with multiple agents. However I could not make it work.

May I know which part am I missing?

My current config looks like this:

[image]

And in each of the agents, I selected "Multi-Agent" on parallelism with number of 2.

But it seems not the one I want.

What I want is, run the first job with `kubectl port-forward` command. And keep it running while second job start running. After second job `Run script` is finished, then the first job can end.

May I know in Azure DevOps is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be actually to use seprate stages. But if you want to use single stage you can do it as follows:

Define variable like this:

[image]

Configure parallelism on the job:

[image]

And then define custom condition on the tasks:

[image]

One task should have `eq(variables['Script'], 'one')` and the other `eq(variables['Script'], 'two')`

You will get two agents runs your jobs but in each job will actually do only one task:

[image]

[image]